# How can I read keys from the key-pair values defined in a YAML using Python Niet?

Tags: python, shell, parsing, yaml

I have a YAML file and I'm using Python niet as a YAML parser to read the file. The YAML file looks like this -

```
configuration:
  warehouse: warehouse-name
  database: database-name
  object_type:
      schema:
        schema1: /path/to/schema1.sql
        schema2: /path/to/schema2.sql
      view:
        schema1.view1:/path/to/view1.sql
        schema2.view2:/path/to/view2.sql
      table:
        schema1.table1:/path/to/table1.sql
        schema2.table2:/path/to/table2.sql
```

Now I can read the values using niet like this -

```
niet ".configuration.object_type.schema.schema1" /path/to/file.yaml
```

The above command will give the output as -

```
/path/to/schema1.yaml
```

But if I use this command, it prints the complete line as the output-

```
niet ".configuration.object_type.schema." /path/to/file.yaml
Output -
schema1: /path/to/schema1.sql
schema2: /path/to/schema2.sql
```

I need both keys and values separately instead of just values. For example, I need to print object_type schema, followed by schema1 and the corresponding path which is /path/to/schema1.sql

```
schema
schema1
/path/to/schema1.sql
```

I wouldn't mind if I have to use 3 commands for the above output.

Comment: You can pipe through 'head -1' and `tail -1' to get the first resp. last line. If you need the second line from N you can pipe through `head -2 | tail -1`

Answer (score 0):

For now this kind of behavior is not allowed by niet.
Indeed, niet's researches are based on [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html). Niet transform all its inputs in python dicts and use jmespath to query this dict, so everything jmespath knows how to do niet also knows how to do, and unfortunately as far as I can see jmespath doesn't allow that.

You can try to play with something like this:

```
$ niet ".configuration.object_type.schema | {schema: join(',', keys(@))}" https://gist.githubusercontent.com/4383/9538953081f2e475903a8208e834b954/raw/97ffc80acc6d9a9293cae44334707419e27fd98f/config
```

The previous command output:

```
schema: schema1,schema2
```

And maybe you will find a way to pipe more subcommands.

For now, based on your question, I'm working on adding the `additional-objects` to allow to pass more than one research and so allow to make more sophisticated outputs:

https://github.com/4383/niet/commit/977a617f628de52fffed3a82fc3cd16a24927171

With this new feature we will be able to run commands like this one:

```
niet ".configuration.object_type.schema" https://gist.githubusercontent.com/4383/9538953081f2e475903a8208e834b954/raw/97ffc80acc6d9a9293cae44334707419e27fd98f/config -f yaml -a ".configuration.object_type.view" ".configuration.object_type.table"
```

Hopefully it help you.

Hervé

Answer (score 0):

With the [new feature](https://github.com/4383/niet/commit/977a617f628de52fffed3a82fc3cd16a24927171) described in my previous comment it would be possible for you to get what you want with one `niet` command, let see an example:

```
$ niet ".configuration.object_type | keys(@)[0]" \
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/4383/9538953081f2e475903a8208e834b954/raw/97ffc80acc6d9a9293cae44334707419e27fd98f/config \
-a ".configuration.object_type.schema.[keys(@)[0], values(@)[0]]"
```

The previous command will output:

```
schema
schema1
/path/to/schema1.sql
```

The command below will also output the same

```
$ niet ".configuration.object_type | keys(@)[0]" \
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/4383/9538953081f2e475903a8208e834b954  /raw/97ffc80acc6d9a9293cae44334707419e27fd98f/config \
-a ".configuration.object_type.schema | keys(@)[0]" \
".configuration.object_type.schema.schema1" \
".configuration.object_type.schema | keys(@)[1]" \
".configuration.object_type.schema.schema1"
```

This new feature will be available with the next version of `niet` (surely version `3.2.0`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the new feature is now released with the new version of niet (3.2.0), so you can install it or upgrade your installation to the version 3.2.0 and then use the previous example that I shared with you.

https://pypi.org/project/niet/3.2.0/

Cheers